# C# sql command parameters not being used?

Tags: c#, sql

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE qcCheckList SET reviewed = @0, errorLevel = @1, comment = @2 WHERE guid = @3 and itemId = @4", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("0", cli.reviewed.Checked);
int errorLevel = 0;
if (cli.error.Text == "Level 1")
    errorLevel = 1;
else if (cli.error.Text == "Level 2")
    errorLevel = 2;
else if (cli.error.Text == "Level 3")
    errorLevel = 3;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("1", errorLevel);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("2", cli.comments.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("3", guid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("4", cli.itemId);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText);
```

When i run this code it doesn't look like my sql command's parameters are being replaced by their actual values. I want to be able to see their values when the command is compiled so i can see if the correct command is being sent. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried including the `@` prefix when adding the parameters?

Comment: `it doesn't look like my sql command's parameters are being replaced by their actual values.` <= What do you mean by this? Also the values do not replace the parameters, the parameters and their values are sent *with* the query.

Comment: You need the @ symbol when adding to the parameter collection... command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", errorLevel);

Answer (score 2):

Answer is based on my assumption that you are expecting the query statement (string) to change. That assumption is based on your wording as well as the last sentence in your code statement.

> Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText);

The query text is not altered, ie. the parameters in the query text are not replaced with the assigned parameter values. The parameters, and their values, are sent *with* the query text to the DBMS for execution. In Sql Server you can see this if you were to profile the Sql Server Instance using Profiler.

---

As a side note I do not recommend you use `AddWithValue`. See also [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Instead just use `Add`. Also you should give meaningful names to your parameters, like "@errorLevel", when you are able to, it makes debugging easier.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@errorLevel", SqlDbType.Int).Value = errorLevel;
```

It is not necessary to prefix the parameter names with "@" when calling `Add` as it will be done for by the method if you did not. It is considered good practice though but that is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

When you are assigning value to the parameters, command string will not change. To see actual values of the parameters you can get values after they are being assigned

```
 foreach (SqlParameter item in command.Parameters)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(item.ParameterName + "=" + item.Value);
 }
```

This will display actual values

Answer (score 0):

dont use @ numbers, but named.. such as @parmReview, @parmError, etc... then the NAMED values are in your

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmReview", cli.reviewed.Checked)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmError", errorLevel);
etc.
```